# using the coordinate perturbation method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the coordinate perturbation technique to the equation:
$$ x''+x+\epsilon x^2=0$$

I know that I start with letting $$x(\epsilon, t)=x_0(t)+\epsilon x_1(t) + \epsilon^2 x_2(t)+ ...$$

then I substitute this into the original equation and gather like powers of $\epsilon$.

the three equations I got are: $$x''_0+ x_0=0$$
$$x''_1+x_1=-x_0^2$$

$$x''_2 + x_2 = 2x_0x_1$$

I am only going to $O(\epsilon^2)$ so I stopped at three equations.

So from the first equation I get $$x_0= \cos t$$

then the second equation becomes $$x''_1+x_1=\cos^2t$$ I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\cos^2{t} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cos{2 t}$.  Then assume the solution takes the form $x_1(t) = a + b \cos{t} + c \cos{2 t}$, and substitute back into the equation for $x_1$.  Then equate coefficients of the respective cosine terms and solve for $a$,$b$, and $c$.

This works because the boundary conditions were already applied for the $x_0$ solution.  Therefore the solution of the higher order terms are inhomogeneous.

Comment: thanks :) I got $$x_1= -1/2 - 1/6 \cos 2t + 2/3 \cos t$$ when I sub this into the last equation along with $$x_0=cost$$ i am battling to solve for $x_2$ .  I am trying to use trig identities to have rewrite it in terms of $$A + B\cos t + C \cos wt$$